# need help on rosserial windows using windows forms

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
rosserial windows works on visual studio win32 console mode but does not work on windows forms mode.  Here is what I have done:

I am porting win32 Console  rosserial_hello_world from http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows/Tutorials/Hello%20World to windows forms in visual studio.  It built successfully but when I run the app but the ROS master on Ubuntu did not receive any data. It works on Win32 console mode.  Please help.  Thanks.

The code for windows forms:

#pragma once

#include 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <windows.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;
char *ros_master = "192.168.186.132";
geometry_msgs::Twist twist_msg;
ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub ("cmd_vel", &twist_msg);
using std::string;

namespace rosserial_hello_world_forms {

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Timer^  timer1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListBox^  listBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
protected: 
private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
```

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
/// 
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// 
void InitializeComponent(void)
{
this->components = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container());
this->timer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Timer(this->components));
this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
this->listBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListBox());
this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
this->SuspendLayout();
//
// timer1
//
this->timer1->Interval = 1000;
this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::timer1_Tick);
//
// button1
//
this->button1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
static_castSystem::Byte(0)));
this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(135, 22);
this->button1->Name = L"button1";
this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(163, 52);
this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
this->button1->Text = L"button1";
this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
//
// listBox1
//
this->listBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
static_castSystem::Byte(0)));
this->listBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
this->listBox1->ItemHeight = 25;
this->listBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(22, 111);
this->listBox1->Name = L"listBox1";
this->listBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(383, 79);
this->listBox1->TabIndex = 1;
//
// textBox1
//
this->textBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 10, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
static_castSystem::Byte(0)));
this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(474, 37);
this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(336, 30);
this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
//
// Form1
//
this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(9, 20);
this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(431, 244);
this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
this->Controls->Add(this->listBox1);
this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
this->Name = L"Form1";
this->Text = L"Rosserial Windows";
this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_Load);
this->ResumeLayout(false);
this->PerformLayout();

```
    }
```

#pragma endregion
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
    twist_msg.linear.x = 5.1;
    twist_msg.linear.y = 0;
    twist_msg.linear.z = 0;
    twist_msg.angular.x = 0;
    twist_msg.angular.y = 0;
    twist_msg.angular.z = -1.8;
    cmd_vel_pub.publish (&twist_msg);

    nh.spinOnce ();
    Sleep (100);
    listBox1->Items->Add("Go robot go!");

}
private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             
    String ^message;

            
    listBox1->Items->Add("Connecting to server at");
    message = gcnew String(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(ros_master));
    listBox1->Items->Add (message);
    nh.initNode (ros_master);
    //Sleep(1000);

    //printf ("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
    listBox1->Items->Add("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
    nh.advertise (cmd_vel_pub);
    //Sleep(1000);
    timer1->Enabled=true;            
}
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    timer1->Enabled=false;      

}
```

};
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260911/need-help-on-rosserial-windows-using-windows-forms/) by [lukevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30229/lukevan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FYI, I have already solved the problem.  I need to call at least nh.SpinOnce() one time in the initialization thread before enable the timer.

---

Originally posted by [lukevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30229/lukevan/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0